# Communities: Custom Domains, DNS & Email

Tags: community, custom-domain

I set up my Community to use a custom domain like `https://community.example.com`, by following the [documented instructions](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_domains.htm&language=en_US) and a CNAME record, and it's working - great!

The challenge is that now we'd like to send and receive emails from `user@community.example.com` as well -- but it looks like we can't set up an MX record (to enable email) on a domain that has a CNAME pointed to Salesforce.

Has anyone else dealt with this?  Any strategies?

**CLARIFICATION**

I don't think this is actually a Salesforce issue, but a DNS issue I'm experiencing with Salesforce (I guess I could move question to ServerFault).

The limitation is that our community subdomain is defined as a CNAME, but our domain registrar won't let us add MX records unless the domain is defined with an A record (I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapping MX records to CNAME's is not technically 'legal' but of course it does work. So if you are dealing with limitations of your DNS providers GUI you might not be able to create the MX record using the CNAME as the host but if your provider or if you host your own DNS server you might find this article helpful in creating MX records for subdomains:

[How should I setup separate MX records for a subdomain?](https://serverfault.com/questions/54800/how-should-i-setup-separate-mx-records-for-a-subdomain)

Comment: Thanks, Eric! This seems like more of a comment/request for clarification, so can you repost as a comment?  I will answer as a comment on the OP.

Comment: Mapping MX records to CNAME's is not technically 'legal' but of course it does work. So are you dealing with limitations of the GUI or can you add custom records? Who is your registrar? Since you mentioned Server Fault I did find this which might help: http://serverfault.com/questions/54800/how-should-i-setup-separate-mx-records-for-a-subdomain

Comment: Good to know, thanks.  I you clean up your answer to include the info from comments, I'd be happy to accept it.